# Build Feature Branch That Changed in Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, branch, tfvc

I'm using Azure DevOps and we changed to a branching pattern and it looks like the following:

- Trunk
- Branches

  - Feature1

    - MySolution.sln
  - Feature2

    - MySolution.sln
  - Feature3

    - MySolution.sln

If I have a developer who is working in Feature2 branch and checks a change in, I want just the Feature2 branch to build in DevOps.  Instead, it's building every solution file found under the Branches folder.

For my **Get sources** portion of the Build, I have a server path of **$/My Team Project Name/Branches**.  Any idea on how to accomplish this?

**UPDATE:** I am using TFSVC and I followed the instructions (as much as applicable to TFSVC) in this link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/ci-build-git?view=vsts&tabs=designer

Comment: Can you share your build task?

Comment: ![Build Task](https://ibb.co/hOxPqf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to configure the build task to build all and Azure DevOps will build only the checked-in branch, there is an open [User voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/10759983-allow-tfvc-build-definitions-to-target-a-specific) for it.

You have a few workarounds but in every new branch you will need to do some work:

1. Clone a build definition and change source mapping, Path filters of triggers for each branch.
2. Add a PowerShell step/task to get recent check-in change by calling [get changesets](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/10759983-allow-tfvc-build-definitions-to-target-a-specific) Rest API, then store the related solution/project files in a variable by using [Logging Commands](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md), then build these solutions/projects
3. Add few Build tasks on the same build definition, a task for each branch, and in the "Control Options" choose "Run this task"  > "Custom condition" and put this:
   `and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.Build.SourceBranchName'], 'Feature{x}'))`, now the build tass will be executed only to the checked-in branch.

Answer (score 0):

Change your build step from `**\*.sln` to a specific branch, or change your workspace mappings to be scoped to only the branch that you want to build.

Comment: But the problem with that is that I would have to go reconfigure DevOps every time we added a new branch for a new feature.  I figured DevOps would be smart enough to determine which branch was changed and build only that branch without me specifying it in a build configuration.

Comment: You figured incorrectly. That's not how it works for TFVC.